# JS bookmarklet to open sites in another site

Tags: javascript, redirect, hyperlink, bookmarklet

I want to make a JavaScript bookmarklet that will redirect to a url to a different url. So if I click an  element or href, it will open it in isitdownrightnow. It could also be disabled by clicking the bookmarklet again.

I have written something that I think should work, it would give every "a" element (not sure if it would work with other links) an event_listener which would on click stop the default execution of the link, and store the href into a variable so I can implement it into the opening of isitdownrightnow, then later remove that event_listener(haven't done that yet).
The problem is that it alerts (which is just to test that I got the link) every single link, but it comes out as undefined.

```
javascript: 
var A = document.getElementsByTagName('A'); 
var link = null
for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++){
  A[i].addEventListener("click", getLink(i)); 
  A[i].addEventListener("click", stopDirect());
}
function stopDirect() {
  event.preventDefault();
}
function getLink(e) {
  link = e.href; 
  alert (link);
}
```

This is the code to open a link in isitdownrightnow

```
window.open("https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/" + thaturl + ".html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="redirect('your_url_here')">Click Me!</a>

<script>
  function redirect(url) {
    window.open(url, "_blank")
  }
</script>
```

You can refer here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 0):

So listen to the click event on the document and read the target path....

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  console.log()
  if (event.target.tagName === "A" && event.shiftKey) {
    console.log(event.target.href); //window.open(....)
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com">test 1</a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">test 2</a>
```